# Nginx permission denied

Tags: nginx, flask

I want to deploy my flask service in a server with centOS 7. So I followed this tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7 .

After runnning `systemctl start nginx` command, I got this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5000 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

My `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 5000;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/root/fiproxy/fiproxyproject/fiproxy.sock;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** flask service and wsgi work ok. And I've tried to run nginx with superuser and the error remains.

Comment: And you run systemctl command with root user? coz thats the only reason i can think of for a permission denied error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After search a lot in Internet, I found a solution to my problem.

I ran this command to get all used ports in  my machine: `semanage port -l`. 
After that, I filtered the output with: `semanage port -l | grep 5000`.

I realized that this port 5000 is used by `commplex_main_port_t`, I searched in speedguide and I found: `5000   tcp,udp **UPnP**`.

Conclusion, maybe my problem was bind a standard port.

To add your desired port use this command:

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp [yourport]
```

Now run nginx with sudo:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: i'm getting this error after running semanage command

ValueError: Port tcp/3306 already defined

Comment: you should change the -a to -m for modifying in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The Nginx **master process** needs root permission. Because it needs bind port.
You need start Nginx under root user.
Then you can define the user of  child processes in **nginx.conf**.

Comment: I'm running the master process with Root. I configured all with root and the problem remains.

Comment: what is the  permission of  fiproxy.sock

Comment: I created a nginx user.